# Assigning value to a register in a module instance in verilog

Tags: verilog

I am a beginner to verilog. I was trying to execute this code to store a value in a register which is in an instance of another module. Here are the two modules.

```
module main;
reg [15:0] A;
wire [15:0] B;
initial
begin
    A = 16'h1212;
end
copy a(B,A);
endmodule  

module copy(B,A);
input [15:0] A;
output reg [15:0] B;
initial
   B=A;
endmodule
```

The code compiles fine but on execution the value of B is 'unknown'. 
If such an assignment is not possible, is there any other way to assign a value to a register in a module instance(from an input to that instance)?

I am using ModelSim Altera Web Edition 6.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `copy` module, change:

```
initial 
   B=A;
```

To:

```
assign B = A;
```

`initial` statements are only evaluated once when simulation begins, and are generally not sythesizable, though some FPGA tools may honor them.

What you want is a continuous assignment, which is what `assign` does.

That should get you to the point where B is the value you expect. Though I should add that this doesn't mean you are assigning an actual hardware register.

EDIT: You also need to remove the `reg` part of the declaration of `outout reg [15:0] B` on the copy module.  You cannot place continuous assignments on `reg` types.

EDIT: To answer your question in the comments, if you want to assign a `reg` you need to do so in a procedural block, e.g. an `always` block that is sensitive to the inputs.

```
always @(A) begin
  B = A;   // B is declared as a reg
end
```

**Just because B is declared as a `reg` type does not mean it is a physical register.**  The two examples here are equivalent and both describe combinational logic.  If you really want a flip-flop, you need to add a clock.

Comment: Thank you, that helped. But is there a way at all to store current input port value in a register?